# Simplify the square of a sum of cosine functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, power-series

I have a square sum of exponantials as below:
$$\left|\sum_{l=0}^{M-1}\exp\left(jl^2a\right)\,\exp\left(\frac{-j2\pi l}{M}b\right)\right|^2 $$

where $a$ is constant and $b$ is an integer .
and I have rewritten the above expression as below
$$\left|\sum_{l=0}^{M-1}\cos\left(l^2a-\frac{2\pi l}{M}b\right)\right|^2 + \left|\sum_{l=0}^{M-1}\sin\left(l^2a-\frac{2\pi l}{M}b\right)\right|^2 $$

how could I simplify $\left|\sum_{l=0}^{M-1}\cos\left(l^2a-\frac{2\pi l}{M}b\right)\right|^2 $

Comment: You can always write such an equation in real form by setting$\exp(a+bi)=e^a*(\cos(b)+i*\sin(b))$ and |a+bi|^2=a^2+b^2, but that doesn't make your equation nice.

Comment: I don't think you can simplify this expression because finite sums of the form $e^{c*k^2}$ are generally to complicated as to yield a closed form expression.

Comment: how about when M is a large number? I mean if we approximate it with the case that M is infinite?

Comment: Then there is a lot of theory around Jacobi's Theta function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function